# Seaborn barplot on multiple lines

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization, seaborn, visualization

I have the following plot made with [`seaborn.catplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.catplot.html):

[image: current barplot]

The barplot is very small and I would like to cut it in half such that the plot looks like this

[image: request barplot]

Here's the code used to generate the current plot

```
sns.catplot(x="model", 
        y="score", 
        hue="metric", 
        data=df, 
        kind='bar',
        height=5,
        aspect=7)
```

Anyone know of any ways of doing this. Thanks